# My m1 Mac throws a error When I update Podfile

Tags: xcode, homebrew, apple-silicon, ruby

When I want to update my Podfile in my Xcode iOS project, the Terminal throw a error like this:

```
Updating local specs repositories /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): tried: '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/usr/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (no such file) - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi_c.bundle (LoadError)
```

is the ruby environmental dose not for my m1 Mac? How can I solve this problem?anybody can help me?

Comment: Can you please format the question so that it is readable it just looks like a screen of rubbish. Use markdown to show logs as code.

Comment: `incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')` should give a clue :-)